# Efficient pre-perl-5.10 equivalent of pack("Q>")

Tags: perl, perl5.10

Update: Salva correctly points out that I was wrong about the introduction of the "Q" pack template. It's the ">" modifier that doesn't go back to 5.8.

Perl 5.10 introduced the pack() modifier ">", which, for my use case with "Q" packs an unsigned quad (64bit) value in *big endian*.

Now, I'm looking for an efficient equivalent for

```
pack("Q>2", @ints)
```

where @ints contains two 64bit unsigned ints. "Q>2" means "pack two unsigned quads in big-endian byte order". Obviously, I want this because I am (at least temporarily) tied to a pre-5.10 Perl.

Update2: Actually, on further reflection, something as simple as the following should do:

```
pack("N4", $ints[0] >> 32, $ints[0], $ints[1] >> 32, $ints[1])
```

Appears to work on my 64bit x86-64 Linux. Any reason why this might not be exactly the same as `pack("Q>2", @ints)`? Any platform-specific matters?

What's the reverse (ie. equivalent to unpack("Q>2", @ints))?

Comment: `scalar reverse pack "Q2", reverse @ints` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Q` pattern was introduced in perl 5.6. Your real problem may be that you are trying to use it in a perl compiled without 64bit support.

Anyway, you can use [Math::Int64](https://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aInt64).

**Update**, an example:

```
use Math::Int64 qw(int64_to_native);
my $packed = join '', map int64_to_native($_), @ints;
```

Another option, if  you are on a 64bit perl supporting `Q` but not `Q>`, is to reorder the bytes yourself:

```
pack 'C*', reverse unpack 'C*', pack 'Q', $int;
```

Comment: Thank you for finding out that I totally misremembered the portability issue: It's ">" that doesn't go back, so the closest thing that enforces big-endian order is the "N" template, which is 32bit/unsigned only. So in spirit, my question stands, but your (previously very valid) answer doesn't quite apply any more. Sorry for that, my bad. PS: This is a 64bit perl.

Comment: Here's what I came up with as the reverse of the pack: `my @tmp = unpack("N4", $out2);
my @orig= ( ($tmp[0] << 32) | $tmp[1], ($tmp[2] << 32) | $tmp[3] );`