# 64 Bit "network" (big-endian) order Integer in Perl

Tags: perl

Similar to how you can use pack's:

```
N  An unsigned long (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.
```

Is there any method for packing a 64-bit integer in "network" (big-endian) order in Perl?

Comment: You just have to find the right format in the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/pack.html) documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your system supports the `Q` pack format, you can use `Q>` to get big-endian (since Perl 5.9.2):

```
% perl -e 'print pack("Q>", 1)' | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01                           |........|
```

Comment: Perfect! I should have RTFM about modifiers before asking. Thanks though.

Comment: I love this 5.10 feature. It solved some weird pack problems for me. :)

Comment: It's after 5.10 according to [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). A great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716331/1831722) would include a way of doing in _before_ 5.10.

Comment: @vesperto it's 2017, why should anyone care about anything before Perl 5.10 ?

Comment: @Alnitak some poor souls still have to use (i.e. no choice) legacy software. ;-)